# PHP COM dll config file

Tags: php, com

Right, I'll try and explain this the best I can.

I'm using PHP COM with a DLL which has a separate config file. Looking at the code of the COM DLL, no path is specified for the config file, only a filename.
Running through command line with the config file in the same directory is successful, however when running through a webpage, it can't find the config file.

Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like a pretty dumb move on the DLL's part. There is no way to specify a full path for the config file?

Comment: Do you have the source code for the DLL so you can change it? This is a pretty common mistake when writing components that can run either locally or on the web; the path to the config file has to work in both cases.

Comment: @Pekka Yea I know it's legacy code back from 2004 - all the code from back then is pretty shocking.

Comment: @Sam I do have the source code but it is used by something else and I've been told I'm not allowed to change it!

Comment: @m4rc, Can't you fork a copy?

Comment: @Brad I think if worse comes to worse I will have to really...

Comment: Hi m4rc, I want to access DLL file by PHP and for that I'm trying to enable COM class but I'm not finding any option on my php.ini file. can you tell me what config file should be or what configuration I should do? I'm using PHP 5.3.5 on local and 5.2.17 on live.

Comment: @Dhaval I don't think that there was any option for it in the php.ini but the com class had to be registered on the system. Eventually, I had to create a bat script to execute the com dll and execute that with php and then take the output of that file. It was nasty but it was for an isolated internal page. Hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try changing the current working directory:

```
chdir('somepath/');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php

**Edit:**  Failing that, try to see if it is relative to the host process executing your script.  For CGI, that's be php-cgi.exe.  For a module, it would be whatever your web server is.  If that is the case, you can make a link in NTFS to some config within your script if necessary.  You might also consider using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to try to figure out what file that DLL is trying to open.  Although, since you have the source code, you should be able to figure that out by looking at it.

Comment: Meant to say that I've tried copying the config to the current working directory and it doesn't work from there.

Comment: Will that help in the context of a COM object though? Well, I guess it has to (looking at the OP's problem description, it clearly seems to be sensitive of the working directory)

Comment: @Pekka, I figured it would, but apparently not.  m4rc, I don't suppose you could use Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and figure out what the file is that it is trying to open?  Maybe something relative to the PHP.exe (if running as CGI) or the web server exe?

Comment: @Brad I'll give Process Explorer a go - I've got nothing to lose! :-p